# Can I use quicky to create enterprise applications?

Tags: application-development, python, quickly

Recently I started using quickly to create Ubuntu applications and I was exploring the possibility of using quickly to create scalable enterprise applications.

Can I use quicky to create such enterprise applications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes

You can use quickly for enterprise applications. Quickly is just a tool which connects editor, visual designer, packaging and sharing. Currently quickly supports python as the programming language, glade as the interface designer and GTK+ as the toolkit.

Choosing it for Enterprise applications is your choice, but I personally recommend QT C++ for enterprise apps.

Answer (score 1):

You can, but you likely need to create new templates for your kind of enterprise apps.  The default Quickly templates create Python desktop and command-line apps.  You can create your own templates to creating J2EE project, or Python/Django webapps, or PHP projects, or whatever it is you need.

Answer (score 0):

Quickly is just a framework/IDE for Python and GTK. So the real question should be if you should use those for an enterprise application. There is the right language for everything, but everyone has a different opinion on that so there is no one right answer.

Personally I wouldn't use Python for enterprise applications or any large application for that matter. It is not very fast and I prefer strongly typed languages for good object oriented modelling which is very important in enterprise applications.

Comment: Quickly can do more than just Python and Gtk, you can extend it by adding templates for just about any kind of project.